# Intercepting Window Close

Tags: python, window, pyqt5

using Python 3.6 and PyQt5 I would like to store the geometry of my main window, when I close my application.
Any solutions already suggested here, like connecting to the QApplications aboutToQuit or overwriting the close method of my MainWindow (derived from QMainWindow) doesn't work.

If I call 'geometry' in the close method, Python crashes. When I try to find the geometry of the main window in the aboutToQuit, the main window has already been destroyed, so this also doesn't work.

Any other suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!
Gerhard

Comment: [QWidget.saveGeometry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#saveGeometry)

Comment: I was wrong. aboutToQuit or overwriting the close method (or better the closeEvent method) can do the job. The problem was, that I had a syntax error in my overloaded methods, which was not reported. Python just crashed and displayed a dialog window "Python has stopped working" - but no error message in the console.
When I removed the syntax error, everything is fine.
Thanks for the pointer to saveGeometry.

Sorry for wasting your time.